# password encrypted twice by md5 in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have been developing an application in Yii framework. I create a registration form where there is a field that is password. After registration, I saw that password result stored in db is being encrypted twice of md5.

I wrote in model as:

```
protected function afterValidate()
{
    $this->password = $this->encrypt($this->password);
}
public function encrypt($value)
{
    return md5($value);
}
```

an in controller

```
public function actionRegistration()
{
    $model=new User('registration');

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
   $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    $model->scenario = 'registerwcaptcha';
    if(isset($_POST['User']) )
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        $keystring = md5( rand(0,1000) ); // Generate random 32 character hash and assign it to a local variable.
        $model->keystring = $keystring;
        //$model->password = md5( $model->password );
        if($model->validate())
        {
            // and here is the actual HACKY part
            $model->scenario = NULL;

            // save user registration
            if($model->save())                                       
                $this->redirect(array('emailverify'));
        }

    }

    $this->render('registration',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Could anybody help me please.

Comment: How you came to know that password encrypted twice?

Comment: 1) MD5 is *not* "encryption". 2) So... change your code to not *hash* it twice...? Implicit changes to data by validation functions are a terrible idea. *Explicitly* hash the password once, not implicitly twice.

Comment: I have a test password, that I insert in table with md5 then I updated again that string with md5 which result match with what saved through registration.

Comment: BTW, MD5 is wholly unsuitable for password protection. It's almost worse than useless, because it makes you believe you are safe when actually your passwords can be brute forced in seconds. Use bcrypt/[password_hash](http://php.net/password_hash).

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of Yii has password hashing build in.

To hash you can use:

`$hash = CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($password);`

and to verify:

```
if (CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($password, $hash)){
    // password matches with hash
}
else{
    // password doesn't match with hash
}
```

For more detailed information take a look at this page:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPasswordHelper/