# MD5 validator for Yii

Tags: validation, yii, md5

The latest version of Yii 1.x [has password hashing build in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477089/1469208). But, do we have a build in MD5 validator, so I can check, if particular field really contains valid MD5 hash?

If not and if I need to write my own myself, is there any source of example, I can reuse (to not re-invent the wheel)? Or do I have to write myself totally from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example validator code:

```
public function validateMd5($attribute, $params)
{
    if(!$this->hasErrors() && $this->password !== '')
    {
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/', $this->password))
            $this->addError('password', 'Password field must contain valid MD5 hash!');
    }
}
```

And this is, how to add it to your model (in `rules()` method):

```
array('password', 'validateMd5', 'on'=>array('create', 'update'))
```

This code only validates, if string entered by user to `password` field is a valid MD5 hash. It  does not validates the password itself. For this purpose you should consider for example `CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword` method (example in 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477089/1469208)).

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! I just let myself re-edit your code, to make it fully-featured Yii validator, instead of just validation function -- what you suggested. Beside this small edit, all the glory goes, of course, to you! :]

Comment: `verifyPassword` uses some matches system, will check it sometime. Good job anyways.